# Exporting 3D object from Poser or Daz to SVG

Tags: export, svg

I am currently working on a human body in Poser which i want to export in SVG. Basically were talking about a 2D export and nothing fancy 3D.

Im really struggling with finding a way to export this, as the only formats that doesn't flatten the object is Collada or Wavefront.

Basically what i'm interested in is to get the human body on a HTML5 page in a scaleable format.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots. Makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Comment: [Here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?327690-Robot-painting-with-a-cycles-maquette) is described an interesting technique, done in Inkscape using a rendered image as reference. It isn't a direct export, but is a way you can follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use another tool to achieve your goal, because SVG not for 3D.

1. Export your model in FBX or OBJ
2. Import three.js library on your html
3. Import your model on html

Please, check documentation and examples
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models